# Playing sounds in an array with the next and back button

Tags: android, arrays, audio

I have three sounds and i am trying to play them when the button is pressed. Now i have two buttons, Next and Back button. The next button will move the array of sounds in the forward direction and obviously play them when clicked, and similarly the back button will play the sounds and move the array in the reverse direction.

Here is the logic i am trying to use:

```
    private int[] sounds = { R.raw.chase, R.raw.get_down,
            R.raw.under_arrest };
    private int pool = 0;
    MediaPlayer mp;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.learn_main);

        Button btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        Button btnBack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);


        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, sounds[pool]);


        // INITIALIZING OVER
        btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if (pool < sounds.length - 1) {
                    pool++;


                } else {

                    pool = 0;
                }           
                mp.???????????


        });

        btnBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if (pool > 0) {
                    pool--;

                } else {

                    pool = sounds.length - 1;
                }
                mp.???????????


            }

        });

    }
}
```

I hope i explained well what i wanted, at-least i tried. Please do let me know if i failed in clarifying my question, i will edit it for that matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to re-initialise the `MediaPlayer` every time you want it to play different result. Here's an example:

```
btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if (pool < sounds.length - 1) {
                pool++;
            } else {
                pool = 0;
            }    

            refreshMediaPlayerWithSound(pool);
    });


btnBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if (pool > 0) {
                pool--;
            } else {
                pool = sounds.length - 1;
            }   

            refreshMediaPlayerWithSound(pool);
    });


private void refreshMediaPlayerWithSound(int pool) {
     if (mp != null) {
         mp.release(); // release any previously played / held resources
     }
     mp = MediaPlayer.create(YourActivity.this, sounds[pool]);      
     mp.start();
}
```

Comment: That worked well, but last thing, how can i set the first sound of the array to play by itself and and the array sequence starts from there?

Comment: For example for image it could have been like img.setImageResource(sounds[pool])

Comment: Well just do mp.start() after it's initialised in the first place (before the click listeners). And don't forget to do pool++ in this case so that the buttons will work as expected.